# To build a docker image in drone get an error "/bin/sh: 1: base64: not found ". How to solve it?

Tags: linux, docker, drone.io

My .drone.yml file is defined as follows

```
branches:
  include: [ master, dev ]
  exclude: [ develop, feature/* ]
clone:
  git:
    image: plugins/git
    depth: 50
workspace:
  base: /go
  path: src/xx.com/metis
pipeline:
  build:
    when:
      branch: master
    image: golang:alpine
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - CGO=0
      - GOOS=linux
      - GOARCH=amd64
      - PATH=$PATH:/go
      - GOPATH=/go
    commands:
      - go env
      - go build -v -o metis
```

To built by drone got error as follows pictures.

["/bin/sh: 1: base64: not found "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKyfz.png)

Comment: Do not use links to provide vital parts of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved ! In .drone.yml file at "environment" node - PATH=$GOPATH/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH destroyed PATH environment . So delete - PATH=$PATH:/go line code will be ok.

https://github.com/drone/drone/issues/2296